# Shrinking element height with delay

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to have 2 headers fade in and out and then i would like the element wrapping to shrink in height.

The problem i'm having is that it does not animate, it just suddenly 'shrinks'. Should i use css animation somehow?

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/37eAC/2/

JQuery

```
$('.section-intro h1').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('.section-intro h2').delay(5000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('.section-intro div').delay(9000).fadeIn(1000);
setTimeout(function(){
   $(".section-intro").addClass("animate");
}, 12000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to do the trick:

```
$('.section-intro').delay(12000).animate({height: "20px"}, 500);
```